# Como funciona a função contains do XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

Tenho um **xml** dessa forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<A x1="ab">
    <B x1="abb">
        <C x1="cc"> Marta </C>
    <B/>
    <B x1="be">
        <C x1="be"> João </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

E utilizei a expressão **XPATH** :

```
//contains(@x1,"b")
```

Pensei que através da função `contains()`, me daria todos os atributos `x1`, com a letra ***b***, no entanto o resultado foi:

```
Boolean='false'
Boolean='true'
Boolean='false'
Boolean='true'
Boolean='false'
Boolean='false'
Boolean='false'
Boolean='false'
Boolean='false'
Boolean='true'
Boolean='false'
Boolean='true'
Boolean='false'
Boolean='false'
```

Alguém consegue me explicar por quê?

Comment: Seu primeiro elemento *B* está finalizado de forma errada corrija para `</B>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) serve para informar se existe algum elemento cujo o atributo contenha determinado valor.

É uma função lógica portanto retorna apenas `true` ou `false`e normalmente é usada como parâmetro.

A expressão que você está procurando é:

```xml
//*[contains(@x1,"b")]
```

Onde a consulta `//*` é o [curinga(wildcard)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#doc-xpath31-Wildcard) significando todos os elementos do documento e a expressão entre colchetes restringe a procura aos elementos cujo o atributo `x1` contenha `b`.

Comment: Muito obrigada. Era isso sim :)

Comment: Feito. Mt obrigada msm kkkkk